# Soft muting small speakers quickly

Tags: audio, bjt, speakers, jfet

I'm running a small 3W speaker from an MP3 module, in order to save power I control the module with a MOSFET switch. The module itself can not go into an very effective low current sleep mode so I have to turn it off. I turn it off only when it is not outputting audio, however I can hear a small pop noise from the speaker when turning off.

What could be a safe / quick & easy / cheap fix for this?
I was thinking about inserting a short (2 Ohm or less) across the speaker or to ground in order to lower the voltage that develops across the speaker. Perhaps this could be switched with a BJT or JFET?

Other ideas?

Comment: You can't really fix this unless you understand the cause.  Most likely it is a result of having a DC bias at the amp output which is blocked by a capacitor.

Comment: it's a small class D amp without an inductor on the output

Comment: [Class D Audio Amplifier POP Analysis and Solutions; Application Note](https://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/GetDocument?id=2583)

Answer (score 1):

That sort of depends on the amplifier in the module.

With lack of other information, safest is a small relay to either switch in/out an extra load resistance when the power drops out. This is best done with a separate control line other than the power line to the AMP so you can sequence the relay around the power application and removal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f82uRG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**UPDATE:** Schematic updated to use a [photo-relay](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=14237&prodName=TLP241A) and show differential speaker drive resistor connection.

Comment: That looks more like disconnecting the speaker than switching in an extra load.  But you probably want to make it disconnect the speaker entirely, and leave the DC block cap driving your weak extra load, such that it can stabilize while the speaker is not in the circuit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ya I was not sure what to do with the other side of the speaker since the OP did not tell us enough to know if it is a single ended amp or not

Comment: @Trevor It is differential.

Comment: @user34920 ok then relay in the resistor into either line.

Comment: @Trevor since this is a small 3W speaker and the case is also rather small, can you recommend an electronic switch instead of the relay?

Comment: @user34920 I do not usually do that, but perhaps one of these... https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/TLP241A-TP1F/TLP241A-TP1FTR-ND/6574627 you will need to add a pull-up for the LED.

Comment: @user34920 I updated the circuit diagram